# Error: Can't find symbol from a class in the same package

Tags: java, class, package

I'm trying to call the class Usuario in the class App. They are in the same package, the same folder, but still, the java compiler is can't find the class.

** I've cloned the code from a repository in github (don't know if that makes any difference).

```
package code;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * App
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // abre  o scanner
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //inicializa alguns usuarios e departamentos
        Usuario user1 = new Usuario("123", "joao", 1);
        

        
        //variaveis do usuario logado
        String id = null;
        String nome;
        int tipo;
        String cargo;
        
        //variavel do fim do programa
        boolean fim_do_programa = false;
        
        System.out.println("Sistema de Controle de Aquisicoes\n");
        

        while(!fim_do_programa){
            

            if(id == null){
                // primeiro acesso deve requerir o login
            }
            
            //  input do usuario
            System.out.print("Digite o a função desejada: ");
            int inputUsuario = teclado.nextInt();

            
            
            switch(inputUsuario){
                case 1 :// Mudar o usuario atual; 
                break;

                case 0 : System.out.println("Fechando o programa...");fim_do_programa = true; break;          
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

The other class in this example is the "Usuario"

```
package code;
import java.util.*;
public class Usuario {

    private String id;
    private Departamento departamento;
    private String nome;
    private static int countUser = 0;
    private int tipo;
    private String cargo;
    
    public Usuario(String codigo, String nome, int tipo) {
        this.id = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        if (tipo == 1 || tipo == 2) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERRO AO CRIAR USUÁRIO " + this.nome + ". Usuário não será criado.\n");
            this.tipo = 0;
        }
        countUser++;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static int getCountUser() {
        return countUser;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        if (this.tipo == 1) {
            this.cargo = "funcionário";
            return this.cargo;
        } else if (this.tipo == 2) {
            this.cargo = "administrador";
            return this.cargo;
        } else {
            this.cargo = null;
            return this.cargo;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [cargo=" + cargo + ", departamento=" + departamento.getDepartamento() + ", id=" + id + ", nome="
                + nome + "]";
    }

}
```

When i try to compile the code, this error keeps showing

```
PS C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\TrabalhoG\trabalhoGCS-PUCRS\code> javac App.java
App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        Usuario user1 = new Usuario("123", "joao", 1);
        ^
  symbol:   class Usuario
  location: class App
App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        Usuario user1 = new Usuario("123", "joao", 1);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Usuario
  location: class App
2 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just compiling it incorrectly.

1. Make sure that `App.java`, `Usuario.java` and `Departamento.java` are all in a directory named `code`.  That is the name of the package.
2. Change directory to the directory *above* the `code` directory.
3. Compile as follows:

   ```
     javac -cp . code/App.java
   ```

If the classpath / sourcepath are correct, then the Java compiler will find previously compiled classes and source files for any of the classes that the class you are compiling (e.g. `code/App.java`) depends on.  If both source and compiled (`.class`) versions are found, the newer is used.  That means that a newer source file be recompiled.  So ... in your example ... `code/Usario.java` and `code/Departamento.java` should be compiled or recompiled.

For more information, read the documentation for the `javac` and `java` commands.  Pay particular attention to the description of the classpath and source path and the `javac` doc's section on "searching for types".

---

Having said that, for anything more complicated than this you should *graduate* to using a Java build tool such as Maven, Gradle or Ant.